# Show pagination for large number of pages in java swing

Tags: java, swing, pagination, paging

I am working on jtable having pagination. I am using DB query to extract rows from database and then set rows to the jtable model. For now, I have more than 7.4 million rows and I am showing 100k rows per page, which generates 74 pagination button, shows in this image.

But I want to show pagination buttons like, showing previous 2 pages and next 2 pages from the current page. and always shows first 3 page and last 3 page. Suppose user is on page 20, so the pagination will work like this :
1,2,3 ... 18,19,20,21,22 ... 72,73,74

here is my code sample which shows what I done so far:

```
private static void createPaginationButtons(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM cdr");
    while (rs.next()) {
        totalRows = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    int v = totalRows % recordPerPage == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    totalPages = totalRows / recordPerPage + v;
    createButton(totalPages);
}
private static void createButton(int totalPages) throws SQLException {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPages;) {
            buttons = new JButton("" + (i + 1));
            buttons.addActionListener(listener);
            panel.add(buttons);
            i++;
        }
        createTable(offSet);

    }
```

These functions is used to create buttons and add them to panel.

[image]

Comment: So you're just asking for help with the logic surrounding which pagination buttons you want to show to the user?

Comment: So you have clear view of what should be done - what is the problem?  It requires couple of if statements and simple arithmetics, nothing more.

Comment: Maybe us a better control, something like `< [1]>` where `[1]` is text field the user can enter the page they want an the `<` and `>` navigate back/forward one page. Maybe even consider using a `JSlider` to help

Comment: Yes, I have done this in the format : First, Previous, TEXTFIELD. Next, Last

Comment: you can create x buttons on start and overwrite the text each time